# write to file with makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How I can write to a file with my makefile?
For example, how to write all .cpp file names in current directory to a file. I need that these names will be each on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use other available tools: `ls -l > somefile`. You can put that command in the makefile.

Comment: Maybe `ls -1 *.cpp > somefile` would be better.